# Re-zip archives with the compression level "No Compression"

Tags: windows, compression, zip, archiving

I am running *Windows 8.1 Enterprise x64*. I have a folder containing hundreds of ZIP archives (aka *Compressed folders*). I need the fastest way to convert them (preferably, in-place) to vaild ZIP archives with the same content and name, but with the compression level *No Compression* (so that all their content would be visible as plaintext if an archive is opened in a text editor).

I need it to be able later compress them using another archiver supporting solid archives and higer compression levels, but still keep them in the original folder in valid ZIP format (expected by some programs).

Comment: You want them  to be individualized archives I assume?

Comment: Yes, after the conversion, there should be the same number of files with the same names as before.

Comment: This will require [Winzip Command Line](http://www.winzip.com/cl-features.html#sub-nav) its fully documented.  You will have to more then likely do the following.  Create a .bat file that goes through each existing file and extract it.  Depending if you what the original files, at this point involves renaming those existing files.  At this point you can then compress each created folder with the required compression.  I** will not write that batch file for you.**

Comment: I know how to write a script or a program to do the task. I hoped there were already some tool that can do this in a couple of clicks.

Comment: You have some very specific requirements.  There is unlikely an existing tool.

Comment: try here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10208241/how-to-repack-zip-files-without-using-tmp-dir -- back in the BBS days, there used to be a utility that would unzip your upload, rezip using max compression, and delete the original upload, then re-name the new zip to the old filename. I'm surprised there isn't a tool to re-zip an existing zip to the compression level you want.